# validation dropdown menu in php

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to validate through php a form, but when I use dropdown it does not work when using the logical operator or "||"

```
<select name="options">
    <option value="">Seleccione idioma</option>
    <option value="Cake">Cake</option>
    <option value="Cookies">Cookies</option>
    <option value="Soda">Soda</option>
    <option value="Water">Water</option>
</select>
```

And this is my code in php

```
if($_POST['options'] != 'Cake' || $_POST['options'] != 'Cookies' || $_POST['options'] != 'Soda' || $_POST['options'] != 'Water' )
```

The code only works fine when in the "if" use only `if($_POST['options']! = 'Cake')`

Comment: That's not valid PHP code, you're missing an `||` in there between the last two comparisons.

Comment: It's also time to meet your new friend: [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Testing the presence in an array is significantly less messy than this sprawling `if` clause.

Comment: suggestion: you can use if($_POST['options']=''){  // your logic }

Comment: That if-statement would _always_ validate as true, since you're using `or`. At least one of those checks will always pass since no matter what it contains, it will always be "not equal" to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather be using `isset()`

```
if(isset(if($_POST['options']))
```

OR

```
if($_POST['options'] != '')
```

OR

Have an `array` and use `in_array`

```
$array = ['Cake', 'Cookies', 'Soda', 'Water'];
if(in_array($_POST['options'], $array)){ // code goes here }
```